# how can I use my own box.com account without prompting the user

Tags: box-api

I have a windows application that gathers files into a single zip file.
I would like my application to upload this zip file to my box.com account.

Is there a way to get the authorization code without prompting the user?
My users don't have (or even know about) box.com and
I already have my app key, client_id and client_secret.

Comment: What kind of application is this? Mobile? Webapp?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a workarround with an webclient like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlButton;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

public class BoxAuth {

private String key;
private String email;
private String password;
private String redirectUrl;
private final String AUTH_URL;

public BoxAuth(String key, String email, String password, String redirectUrl) {
    super();
    this.key = key;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.redirectUrl = redirectUrl;
    this.AUTH_URL = "https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" + key + "&redirect_uri=" + this.redirectUrl;
}

public String authorize() throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    System.out.println("AUTHORIZING: " + AUTH_URL);

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);

    HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage(AUTH_URL);
    final HtmlPage grantAccessePage = this.authorizeLogin(loginPage);
    return this.authorizeGrantAccess(grantAccessePage);

}

private HtmlPage authorizeLogin(HtmlPage page) throws IOException {

    final HtmlForm loginForm = page.getFormByName("login_form");
    loginForm.getInputByName("password");
    final HtmlTextInput emailField = (HtmlTextInput) loginForm.getInputByName("login");
    emailField.setValueAttribute(this.email);
    final HtmlPasswordInput passwordField = (HtmlPasswordInput) loginForm.getInputByName("password");
    passwordField.setValueAttribute(this.password);
    final HtmlSubmitInput loginButton = loginForm.getInputByName("login_submit");

    final HtmlPage result = loginButton.click();
    try {
        final HtmlForm test = result.getFormByName("login_form");
        throw new Exception("BoxAPI: Wrong login data!!!");
    } catch (ElementNotFoundException e) {
    }

    return result;
}

private String authorizeGrantAccess(HtmlPage grantAccessePage) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    final HtmlForm grantAccessForm = grantAccessePage.getHtmlElementById("consent_form");
    final HtmlButton grantAccess = grantAccessForm.getButtonByName("consent_accept");

    final HtmlPage codePage = grantAccess.click();

    URL url = codePage.getUrl();
    String result = "";

    if (url.toString().contains("&code=")) {
        result = url.toString().substring(url.toString().indexOf("&code="));
        result = result.replace("&code=", "");
    }

    return result;
}

}
```

as redirect_url u can use something like "https://app.box.com/services/yourservice"

Comment: Thank you for the answer Brokando, but this won't work for me. I am using WinForms and C#. I don't have a "service". This is not a web based application.